# Magento 1.7.0.2 counting double the tax amount when on custom price

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

We have a problem with the Magento 1.7.0.2 webshop, that when we change the price to Custom price and the quantities to more than 1, the counted tax is doubled, so instead of 27% it is 54%. 
The calculation works correctly when counting the custom price for 1pcs or for regular prices at any number of pieces.

Any help how to solve this, please?

Best Regards,
gaspar

Answer (score 0):

Could the problem be that a total object belongs to an address object and Magento orders typically have TWO addresses - one for shipping and one for billing?

$address->getAddressType()